# Using SBT to manage projects that contain both Scala and Python

Tags: python, scala, sbt

In a current project, I've built Python code for interacting with a specific datasource; now, I'm working on building a Scala version.

I've rearranged things so that all of the Python code lives in `src/main/python` within the SBT project for my Scala code, but this got me thinking: Is there any nice way to integrate the project management between the two?  To set up SBT so that I can run my Python `distutils` installation/sdist generation or sphinx document generation as SBT tasks?

Or, more generally: Is there a standard method for running arbitrary system tasks by way of SBT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html):

> sbt includes a process library to simplify working with external
>   processes. The library is available without import in build
>   definitions and at the interpreter started by the consoleProject task.
>
> To run an external command, follow it with an exclamation mark !:
>
> ```
> "find project -name *.jar" !
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a python task which zips the source files. This example depends on the assembly task:

```
  lazy val pythonAssembly = TaskKey[Unit]("pythonAssembly", "Zips all files in src/main/python")

  lazy val pythonAssemblyTask = pythonAssembly := {
    val baseDir = sourceDirectory.value
    val targetDir = assembly.value.getParentFile.getParent
    val target = new File(targetDir + s"/python/rfu-api-client-python-${Commons.appVersion}.zip")
    val pythonBaseDir = new File(baseDir + "/main/python")
    val pythonFiles = Path.allSubpaths(pythonBaseDir)

    println("Zipping files in " + pythonBaseDir)
    pythonFiles foreach { case (_, s) => println(s) }
    IO.zip(pythonFiles, target)
    println(s"Created $target")
```

Answer (score 5):

To run **Python** unit tests of python code **with SBT** test tasks I did this in **build.sbt**:

```
//define task that should be run with tests.
val testPythonTask = TaskKey[Unit]("testPython", "Run python tests.")

val command = "python3 -m unittest app_test.py"
val workingDirectory = new File("python/working/directory")

testPythonTask := {
  val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
  s.log.info("Executing task testPython")
  Process(command,
    // optional
    workingDirectory,
    // optional system variables
    "CLASSPATH" -> "path/to.jar",
    "OTHER_SYS_VAR" -> "other_value") ! s.log
}

//attach custom test task to default test tasks
test in Test := {
  testPythonTask.value
  (test in Test).value
}

testOnly in Test := {
  testPythonTask.value
  (testOnly in Test).value
}
```